# byte array at specyfic addres c++

Tags: c++, memory, arrays

I want to map some part of process memory as byte array.
How to do it?

I have byte array:

```
byte AmmoBytes[3]
```

And I want this array to start at address 0xXXXXXXX;
How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
byte (& a)[3] = *reinterpret_cast<byte (*)[3]>(0xDEADBEEF);
```

Comment: just for the record, what is the type of `byte (*)[3]` ?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: It is a **pointer to array** of 3 byte elements.

Comment: so, in this case, `a` is a reference to a 3 element byte array that is bound to memory address 0xDEADBEEF?

Answer (score 3):

```
byte * AmmoBytes = (byte *) 0xXXXXXXXX;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is unsafe, but you can say

`byte * AmmoBytes = (byte *) 0xXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can't reliably do this.

If `0xXXXXXXX` represents hardware address(es) then you'll need to write a device driver to gain kernel access to the memory.

If it's a normal memory address then there's no guarantee that it maps to a valid memory location and you're quite likely to crash your program.

What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Kernel access is not required on many simple embedded systems.  Just loading the address into a pointer is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare the memory using a *constant* pointer:

```
byte * const AmmoBytes = (byte * const) 0xFFFF000;
```

Declaring the pointer as constant helps the compiler detect errors such as mistakenly changing the pointer value instead of the value pointed to by the pointer.